# Create Shadows for internal nested protected class in Robolectric

Tags: java, android, testing, android-testing, robolectric

I know that creation of custom shadows should be avoided, but my usecase is I have an Activity that implements a custom created widget which needs to be tested using Robolectric. While i call OnCreate from robolectric the test case fails because of Custom Widget.

So i need to write custom shadows for the class, my initial problem is my class to be referenced using **org.robolectric.annotation.Implements.Implements()** is an Inner nested protected class.

My code blocks looks as follows...

```
Class A{
  protected Class  B extends RadioGroup{

  }
}
```

I'm able to access A.class but not B.class in **@Implements**. 
Is there any way to access **Class B** from **@Implements** of Robolectric.

Thanks in advance any help is appreciated......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can achieve this by using

@Implements(A.B.class)